# Debugging between different pages with xDebug in Netbeans

Tags: php, firefox, netbeans, xdebug

I'm using Netbeans 7.4, PHP 5.4.13, php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9 and I'm debugging with Firefox 24

So debugging works just fine, I don't have any problems with debugging a specific file, be it **index.php** or **search.php** or whatever.

My problem is, suppose that I'm debugging **index.php**, and on that page, there is a link to **search.php**. I click on that link, the debug session in Netbeans still goes on, except that the browser doesn't. So if I have breakpoints in **search.php**, it won't stop there.

So again, what I want is, that whenever I click a link from **page A** to **page B**, I want to be able to continue debugging on **page B**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated xDebug to version 2.2.3 which apparently fixes my problem.